# Cannot print individual string with random.choice, only single characters

Tags: python, xml

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random

tree = ET.parse('news.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

channel = root.find('channel')

for item in channel.findall('item'):
    title = item.find('title').text
    description = item.find('description').text
    link = item.find('link').text
    print random.choice(title)
```

This prints out one random character from each title object. I would like to print out one entire title string. This is the original xml file: http://www.11alive.com/rss/local/3/10.xml

Comment: Put all the titles in a list and `random.choice` the list.

Comment: In your for loop, when you `print random.choice(title)` you have only 1 title in the `title` variable, what you need to do is append all the titles to a list and at the end of for loop, `print random,choice(random)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `for` loop to do this:

```
titles = []

for item in channel.findall('item'):
    titles.append(item.find('title').text)
    description = item.find('description').text
    link = item.find('link').text

print random.choice(titles)
```

This will print a random title from the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing, thanks for the tips:

```
titlelist = []

for item in channel.findall('item'):

    title = item.find('title').text
    description = item.find('description').text
    link = item.find('link').text
    titlelist.append(title)

print random.choice(titlelist)
```

Comment: Why set `description` and `link` at all then?

Comment: Also, this is what Volatility posted, why not just accept that answer instead of posting your own?

Comment: I guess I had an answer by the time I came back to the page and wanted to show my answer, which was slightly different (longer) than Volatility's.